# Permission Denied error while creating database in hive

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to database in hive, but when I run below query in HIVE:

```
CREATE DATABASE BIGDATA;
```

I receive the following error message:

> FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=aseema, access=WRITE, inode="":hduser:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x)
>   FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask

**What is causing this?**

Comment: It simply says that you don't have the right to write to the database. Check if your permissions are correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the lack of permission to the user aseema in hdfs. Follow the steps below.

Login as hduser and perform the following operations (from the logs, it seems hduser is a superuser)

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hive/warehouse
hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp
hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /user/hive
hadoop fs -chmod 777 /tmp
```

After this, try executing the create database statement from aseema user.

Comment: i was working in netbeans and this error killed my almost 1 hour. but which the help of these commands now i am able to create table and manipulate it.

Comment: This does works but it is an ugly & insecure bad practice. How would you deal with that in production environment ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running from Local Mode then you should run this command from hdfs user:

```
su hdfs
```

Then change the permission like below if you want:

```
hdfs dfs -chown -R <username_of_new_owner> /user
```