# Issue with Hive and Google Cloud Storage

Tags: hive, google-cloud-storage

Please advice:

I have installed a `hadoop 2.6.5` version cluster in GCP using VM's instances. Used GCP connector and pointed by hdfs to use gs bucket. Added the below 2 entries in `coresite.xml`:

```
google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile=<Path-to-the-JSON-file> 
fs.gs.working.dir=/
```

When using hadoop gs -ls / works fine , but when I am creating a hive tables

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test1256(name string,id  int)   LOCATION   'gs://bucket/';
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error,
>   return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.
>   MetaException(message:java.security.AccessControlException: Permission
>   denied: user=hdpuser1, path="gs://bucket/":hive:hive:drwx------)
>   (state=08S01,code=1)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message implies, you encountered a permissions issue. First, check your Google Cloud Console to make sure you have [Cloud Storage IAM permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions) to perform that action. Next, make sure you have the right permissions for the "hdpuser1" user in hdfs:

- Login as the hdfs user: `su hdfs`
- You can also change the permissions: `hdfs dfs -chown -R <username_of_new_owner> /user`

Then perform the following:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hive/warehouse
hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp
hadoop fs -chmod -R 777 /user/hive
hadoop fs -chmod 777 /tmp
```

Then try creating the Hive table again. I hope that helps.

Find a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32211487/permission-denied-error-while-creating-database-in-hive). And a complete guide in GitHub for [performing a test with Hive](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-apache-hive-and-pig-on-google-compute-engine#hive-test)

Answer (score 0):

I had just this error today and was able to resolve it by adding two following properties:

```
fs.gs.reported.permissions=777
fs.gs.path.encoding=uri-path
```

*both* into core-site.xml and hive-site.xml (by going to advanced configs of HDFS and Hive services in ambari).

If you configure it just in core-site.xml, then hive external table creation will fail.